# How would you create a server without port-forwarding for a website?

Tags: php, mysql, networking, server, web-development-server

I'm at school and in on Campus housing which means I don't have access to the router to get the admin password to allow me to port-forward my website for my senior Capstone. I would like to know how to host a server that I can insert a **MySql** database, as well as my sight files from my own machine; how would I even go about getting around this without port forwarding?

There is an "Open Windows Firewall Ports for network access" embedded within MySQL Server download prosses theoretically if clicked would it allow me to embed a Website within MySQL Server and host it??  or would that just allow my database to be assessable threw my vulnerable network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use reverse proxy services like https://pagekite.net/

Comment: There is an "Open Windows Firewall Ports for network access" embedded within MySQL Server download prosses theoretically if clicked would it allow me to embed a Website within  MySQL Server and host it??

Comment: No, this option would only allow the other devices on the network to access the MySQL server. From what I understood, you want to access the server on the same device the website is hosted. Given that, for better security, I would suggest not to click that option.